# R how to get a result like expand.grid, but control the order of the expansion?

Tags: r

The expand.grid gives the results ordered by the last entered set, but I need it based on the first set.

Given the following code:

```
expand.grid(a=(1:2),b=c("a","b","c"))
  a b
1 1 a
2 2 a
3 1 b
4 2 b
5 1 c
6 2 c
```

Notice how column a changes most often with b less often.

The algorithm it seems is lock the 2nd or Nth variable b and then alternate the 1st or (N-1) variable until the grid gets to every combination possible in the grid.

I need to expand.grid or a similar function that first sets the 1st variable and then adjusts the 2nd variable and so on until it gets to all N.

The desired result for the example is:

```
  a b
1 1 a
2 1 b
3 1 c
4 2 a
5 2 b
6 2 c
```

One way I that works for the example is simply to order by column a, but that does not work as I would need to be able to order by N columns in order and I have not found a way to do so.

It seems so trivial, but I cannot find a way to get expand.grid to behave like I need.

Any solution must work on any arbitrary number of entries to expand.grid and of any arbitrary size. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to do so

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- expand.grid(a=(1:2),b=c("a","b","c"))

df %>% 
  arrange_all()
```

Comment: Thanks that works, basically the quick sort I wanted. Can you please add an explanation or link to how **%>% arrange_all()** works. Google was unhelpful.

Comment: I used the help dplyr 
`?arrange_all`

Comment: The question is about the **%>%** I can find arrange_all() but nowhere can I find %>% which I think just tells it to go in decreasing order. and the documentation does not help me sort without the **%>%**. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `crossing` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(a = 1:2, b = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#      a b    
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 a    
#2     1 b    
#3     1 c    
#4     2 a    
#5     2 b    
#6     2 c
```

Comment: Thank you, the first test I tried was **crossing(1:10,1:10,1:10)** which works with expand.grid, but it gave me a must not be duplicated error. And the crossing documentation has the first example of **%>%** I have found. Thanks again.

Comment: @MichaelE you need to specify the column name `crossing(a = 1:10,b = 1:10,c = 1:10)` THe argument is `...` so it would take the value as column name if not specified and siince all the values are 1:10, it is duplicate column name

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base-R solution, that works with any amount of variables without knowing the content beforehand.

Gather all the variables in a list, with the desired order in which you want to expand. Apply a reverse function `rev` first on the list in `expand.grid` and a second time on the output to get the desired expanding result.

Your example:

```
l <- list(a=(1:2),b=c("a","b","c"))
rev(expand.grid(rev(l)))
#>   a b
#> 1 1 a
#> 2 1 b
#> 3 1 c
#> 4 2 a
#> 5 2 b
#> 6 2 c
```

An example with 3 variables:

```
var1 <- c("SR", "PL")
var2 <- c(1,2,3)
var3 <- c("A",'B')
l <- list(var1,var2,var3)
rev(expand.grid(rev(l)))
#>    Var3 Var2 Var1
#> 1    SR    1    A
#> 2    SR    1    B
#> 3    SR    2    A
#> 4    SR    2    B
#> 5    SR    3    A
#> 6    SR    3    B
#> 7    PL    1    A
#> 8    PL    1    B
#> 9    PL    2    A
#> 10   PL    2    B
#> 11   PL    3    A
#> 12   PL    3    B
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```r
expand.grid(b=c("a","b","c"), a=(1:2))[, c("a", "b")]
#>   a b
#> 1 1 a
#> 2 1 b
#> 3 1 c
#> 4 2 a
#> 5 2 b
#> 6 2 c
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank  you, that is exactly what I did at first and it works, but it fails with any larger or undetermined sets as I need to always renter them in reverse order.